# LINQ filter values based on the selected values of the CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to use a where clause from the values in a dynamically generated CheckBoxList as the filter criteria for a LINQ query.

There are four fields which need to be filtered based on values of the CheckBoxList.

How would I go through each of the fields and compare it with the selected values of the CheckboxList?

I have added "checkBoxListTreeTypes.selectecd values" as an example.

Sample code below...

```
    IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Forest>> forestQuery =
    from test in forest
    where (test.tree1 == checkBoxListTreeTypes.selectedvalues)
    && (test.tree2 == checkBoxListTreeTypes.selectecdvalues)
    && (test.tree3 == checkBoxListTreeTypes.selectecdvalues)
    && (test.tree4 == checkBoxListTreeTypes.selectecdvalues)
    orderby test.name
    group test by test.TrunkSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you go through the CheckBoxList (not tested, but you get the idea):

```
checkBoxListTreeTypes.Items.Any(item => item.Selected && item.Value==test.tree1) &&
checkBoxListTreeTypes.Items.Any(item => item.Selected && item.Value==test.tree2) &&
checkBoxListTreeTypes.Items.Any(item => item.Selected && item.Value==test.tree3) &&
checkBoxListTreeTypes.Items.Any(item => item.Selected && item.Value==test.tree4)
```

You could also put your four trees in an array:

```
string[] trees = new string[] { test.tree1, test.tree2, test.tree3, test.tree4 };
```

and then test:

```
checkBoxListTreeTypes.Items.Count(item => item.Selected && trees.Contains(item.Value)) == 4
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It doesn't like the "..Items.Any". I'm using the using System.Linq namespace. Is there another namespace I need?

Comment: OK, obviously the items collection is of type IEnumerable and not IEnumerable<T> as required for LINQ. Therefore it must be casted with:

checkBoxListTreeTypes.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(...